# Process to remove transparent background of an image plane automatically? (not alpha texture to transparency problem)

Tags: modeling, animation, add-on, transparency, 2d

what I'm looking for is a way, after using "import image as plane" or [camera plane](https://gitlab.com/lfs.coop/blender/camera-plane/-/blob/master/README.md)
to have the transparent background removed and just keep the visible parts of the image plane, so I can transform them to a mesh. (I cannot used SVG files because I want to keep the transparent shading of the edges of the elements)

Do you know if such an addon exists? If not, can you think of another process to achieve it automatically, instead of tracing the image with vertices and curves?

It's for 2d animation work, not using the grease pencil but traditional elements such as in the picture below, (even when imported individually, each png element has a canvas frame generated).Having this would be very time-saving and allow me to uses mesh deformers such as lattice, weight paint+vertex group more accurately.

[image: texture_atlas]

Thanks in advance for your help! and sorry if my English is no the best and a bit confusing haha
LaumeB

Answer (score 0):

So in case somebody else is looking for the same thing, I've actually just found some useful addons for this knid of 2d animation workflow: (one of them is not free tho, but very convenient)

[Leafig Addon (not free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQckQBNHRMA)
[Boundary align remesh addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7gyFAA1HLXU)
[COA Tools Spine softaware free alternative](https://blender-addons.org/coa-tools-addon/)

Also noticed it’s possible to use the “generate pencil grease” in the image editor which can do the trick of removing the transparent BG for some elements too.

Cheers!